# Cocos2d on iOS: 2d billiard zooming

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make a pool game where the user can pinch the pool table to zoom so he can 
precisely shoot the pocket.

So, this means I need a large pool table graphic.

What is the best way to handle such a situation in cocos2d?

How do I load the graphic? What is the limitation on graphic size?

I have a lot of doubts because Im not sure which path to take.

Regards
Mirza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something as simple as a pool table it might be better to render it all using vector graphics. This means you will need less graphics (perhaps only a few for textures) and you get infinite zooming without all the graphic image overhead.

Comment: thx, but how do I save the vector, as png and import it simply into cocos2d? or is there a better format suited for vectors?

Comment: Vector graphics are not images, they are instructions you program like draw from x1,y1 to x2,y2.

Comment: Quartz 2D is fundamental: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Also if peoples answers help you on StackOverflow you should mark the answer as correct, so they get a benefit for helping. It also improves YOUR Accept score which makes it more likely that others will answer your questions in future.